# GDAL Installation -> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, gdal

I am trying to install 'GDAL' python package in conda. Following are the various steps I followed for the installation.

1. Create a new environment

```
conda create -n gdal_py37 python=3.7
```

2. Activating the new environment

```
conda activate gdal_py37
```

3. Executing requirements file shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74651331/not-able-to-install-requirement-s-txt-file-in-my-conda-environment).

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

4. From Anaconda Navigator-> environments-> 'gdal_py37' -> select gdal package from uninstalled packages -> Apply
5. Implemented below line of code in python

```
import gdal
```

6. Following is the error occurring

```
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_18824\1419450745.py in <module>
      7 import os
      8 import sys
----> 9 import gdal
     10 import glob
     11 from tqdm import tqdm

c:\Users\<<User>>\.conda\envs\gdal_py37\lib\site-packages\gdal.py in <module>
      1 # import osgeo.gdal as a convenience
----> 2 from osgeo.gdal import deprecation_warn
      3 deprecation_warn('gdal')
      4 
      5 from osgeo.gdal import *

c:\Users\<<User>>\.conda\envs\gdal_py37\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py in <module>
     19                 fp.close()
     20             return _mod
---> 21     _gdal = swig_import_helper()
     22     del swig_import_helper
     23 else:

c:\Users\<<User>>\.conda\envs\gdal_py37\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py in swig_import_helper()
     15         if fp is not None:
...
--> 342         return _load(spec)
    343 
    344 else:

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably a compatibility issue with another package. This can easily happen when you are using conda with `pip`. Here are two things you should consider:

1. When using conda you don't want to use `pip` because it often leads to package incompabilities as pointed out above. Use the conda package manager together with `environment.yml`files ([conda docs | managing environments](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-from-an-environment-yml-file))
2. When working with geodata, datascience, etc. in conda, you really should use the `conda-forge` [channel](https://conda-forge.org/index.html).

---

Add the `conda-forge` channel by running

```bash
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda config --set channel_priority strict
```

If you did not remove your non-functioning environment yet, do it with `conda env remove -n gdal_py37`.

Create a file `environment.yml` which replaces your `requirements.txt` and should look like this:

```yaml
name: gdal_py37
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - gdal=3.5.2
  - python=3.7
```

Create your environment with its dependencies by running:

```bash
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

Activate your environment with `conda activate gdal_py37`.

Now start `python` and run the following:

```py
from osgeo import gdal
```

Comment: I followed the steps you suggested. Now I'm getting the below error                 
 ``` ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 1
----> 1 import gdal

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gdal' ```                                       
 while implementing the line ``` import gdal```

Comment: I edited and clarified my answer, it should work now. Originally I also pinned the wrong gdal version in the `environment.yml`. The important part is `from osgeo import gdal`.